# Update value of one record with the value of another record in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-update, drupal-webform

I've got a tough SQL question for you guys.
I am working with the Webform module of drupal.

How this module works: 
- every item on the webform is a new record in the 'webform_submitted_data'-table, 
- sid = registered user 
- cid = webform field

Structure of the table:

> NID | SID | CID | NO | DATA
>
> 1 --- 168 --- 1 --- 0 --- XXX
>
> 1 --- 168 --- 2 --- 0 --- YYY

The problem:
- CID 64 should get updated with the value of CID 56 of the same SID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be as follows:

```
UPDATE webform_submitted_data as a, webform_submitted_data as b 
SET a.data = b.data WHERE a.sid = b.sid AND a.cid = 64 AND b.cid = 56
```

Basically, you self-join the table (matching SIDs) and then you have both fields in your query, so you can simply refer to each at once.

Comment: almost correct, but it is not the cid that should get copied but the data of that cid :)

Answer (score 1):

This would copy the Data of CID 56 to CID 64, for each value of SID.  It's SQL Server syntax.

```
update  yt64
set     Data = yt56.Data
from    YourTable yt64
join    YourTable yt56
on      yt64.SID = yt56.SID
where   yt64.CID = 64
        and yt56.CID = 56
```